# Not Looping MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm not sure how to approach this loop. I've seen various ways and tried the `If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then` in various ways but it only goes through the coding once. This code is supposed to loop through table Intake that meet the SELECT query's criteria. There are definitely multiple records that meet this query so it should be looping more then once. This code does work the first time and gives the message box but then just ends. Thank you :)

```
Set db = CurrentDb

i = Me.searchlat

strSQL = "SELECT IntakeID, Program, applicationdate From Intake 
WHERE Status Not Like 'Approved' And Status Not Like 'Denied' And Status 
Not Like 'Withdrawn' And Status Not Like 'Incomplete Application' And Status 
Not Like 'No Show' AND workerid = '" & i & "'"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

While Not rs.EOF

If Me.Program = "CF" And Me.applicationdate < Date - "25" Then
MsgBox ("The following cases are nearing 30 days pending:" & " " & Me.caseid)
rs.MoveNext
End If
Wend
```

Comment: use while (Not rs.Eof ) ... WEND

Comment: Hi @Tim3880 I had used the WEND but it didn't loop through the coding again, I'm not sure if I didn't place it in the right place, but it skipped the strSQL.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question and I will delete the answer. If you want to loop through a dataset (Me) and do different queries, you should put the "Set rs = ..." in your loop.

Comment: It's okay @Tim3880 I put the `Set rs =...` but it's still not selecting the next record. When I put the strSQL in query design it's selecting all of the records, so I know that there are multiple records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your select query you are not selecting the `caseid`. change your select query as

```
"SELECT IntakeID, Program, applicationdate,caseid From Intake.......
```

and check.

```
 strSQL = "SELECT IntakeID, Program, 
applicationdate, caseid From Intake WHERE Status Not Like 'Approved' 
And Status Not Like 'Denied' And Status Not Like 'Withdrawn' 
And Status Not Like 'Incomplete Application' And Status 
Not Like 'No Show' AND workerid = '" & i & "'"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    While Not rs.EOF


If Me.Program = "CF" And Me.applicationdate < Date - "25" Then
    MsgBox ("The following cases are nearing 30 days pending:" & " " & rs!caseid)
End If
rs.MoveNext

Wend
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, move the `rs.MoveNext` outside the If statement but still in the loop.

Currently, the code enters loop and where the `if` condition does not apply, exits the loop (since it does not see a command to move to next record).

Also, sometimes it helps, before the While/Wend loop add the following to be sure recordset is positioned at the beginning:

```
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
```

Comment: I did both things and it's still not selecting the next record. It's looping the number of times correctly, but in the `msg` for `& " " & Me.caseid)` and it should be the new records caseid.